What do the inradius and midradius of the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra actually measure?
In the Platonic Solids, the inradius is the distance from the center of each solid to the center of one of its faces, the midradius is the distance from the center of each solid to the midpoint of one of its edges, and the circumradius is the distance from the center of the solid to one of its vertices.

In the Kepler-Poinsot Polyhedra, it's obvious the that circumradius still measures the distance from the center to each vertex, but the middle of each shape is murkier.  Are the inradius and midradius just the inradius and midradius of the core Platonic solid inside the stellated dodecahedra?  What distances do they measure in the other two?  I tried a few internet searches and didn't come up with anything helpful.

In the Small Stellated Dodecahedron (top-left in image), the faces are the $12$ pentagrams (not the $60$ little isosceles triangles); the inradius and midradius measure the distances from the center to the planes and edges of those, which align with the planes and edges of the "core" dodec's pentagons. Likewise for the top-right. Lower-left, the face-planes again coincide with the core's, but edges coincide with the "surrounding" poly's, so inradius and midradius match corresponding elements of those separate Platonics. Lower-right is different still, as edges align with a third Platonic.

Independent of convex or not,

circumradius = distance from center of polyhedron to its vertices
midradius = distance from center of polyhedron to its edge centers
inradius = distance from center of polyhedron to its face centers

Obviously a unique center of the polyhedron is required for each of those notions.
In order to have a unique circumradius it would be best to require that the polyhedron itself is at least isogonal. Thence uniform or regular polyhedra would match. But you well could classify the vertex set into subsets, each of which then has a specific common circumradius for vertices of that type.
Same applies by duality to the inradius. Thus for uniform polyhedra you usually have several face types. However each face type (eg. under global symmetry) has a specific common inradius.
You could estimate that the same holds (with according adaptions) for edge classes too.
Eg. regular polyhedra generally have all 3 radii unique because all vertices, all edges, and all faces are carried transiently by symmetry all over. Moreover you'll get (from dualization) that here $C\cdot I = M^2$ must hold: just consider the sphere of reciprocation to be the midsphere (i.e. of midradius size).
--- rk

Thanks :-)  So the inradius and midradius of the stellated dodecahedra are the same as the inradius and midradius of the dodecahedron and icosahedron that make up their cores, right?

yes, that's correct
