looking for help deriving surface area and volume formulas of great icosahedron
Edit: My previous inquiry about deriving the inradius has been solved.
I have been working on deriving the surface area and volume formulas, ideally without the use of coordinates, and have found it to be the most difficult of the Kepler-Poinsot Polyhedra.

I was hoping someone could help calculate angles $\alpha$ and $\theta$ relative to the edges E and E$\varphi$ (the brown section shows that the purple triangle is not a right triangle) using trig and verify that the volume of the great icosahedron is the volume of the dodecahedron core minus the volume of the excavated pentagrammal pyramids with depth d plus the volume of the pentagrammal pyramids with height h (which is the volume of a pentagonal pyramid minus the volume of the 5 triangular pyramids around the edges).  (I'm doing it this way because I'd like to take the simplest possible, ideally high-school level, approach to calculating each angle and deriving each formula.)
Edit: Here is another illustration that better shows the triangles I need to calculate the areas of: the reddish-pink and brown ones plus the transparent blue one.


There are elements of answer here. Have you been exploiting them ?

$R_i$ is depicted wrong. The inradius is not a radius to the deepest dimple of a polytope, nor to such of any (symmetrical) dissection thereof, rather it is defined to be the distance from the center to a specific facet type. I.e. for the regular polyhedron in question it simply is the distance from the center to the triangular face (centers). - Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5000639/what-do-the-inradius-and-midradius-of-the-kepler-poinsot-polyhedra-actually-meas

@Dr. Richard Klitzing Thanks for your comment.  If the apex of the excavated pyramid isn't the center of the face outlined in black, where is the center relative to the reddish brown pyramids?

@Dr. Richard Klitzing I'm assuming I should draw the medians of the triangle outlined in black to find its center and then set up a right triangle between the triangle's circumradius, the polyhedron's inradius, and the polyhedron's circumradius.  I just visually assumed the excavated pyramid's apex was the triangle's center.  Is my approach to calculating the volume correct?  I could award you the bounty if you can leave an answer with that and the approach to calculating the angles.

Once again, the inradius is measured as perpendicular to the faces, i.e. from the midpoint of the triangles (eg the one outlined by black lines) to the body center. The circumradius OTOH is measured as the distance from any vertex to the body center. Thus the latter is visible along the 5-fold axes, whereas the former is visible along the 3-fold axes.

With help from a few other members I was able to derive the formulas.






To derive the volume, we first need to derive the height of each pentagonal pyramid of the great icosahedron's small stellated dodecahedron frame.










As to your comment "I'm assuming I should draw the medians of the triangle outlined in black to find its center and then set up a right triangle between the triangle's circumradius, the polyhedron's inradius, and the polyhedron's circumradius.": $\rightarrow$ yes.
Being the great icosahedron, it surely has the same vertices as a $v:=\frac 1\varphi$-scaled icosahedron (where $f:=\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is the golden ratio). Therefrom one derives the following "lace city" (parallel projection) for the icosahedron
 o   o 
   f   
x     x
   f   
 o   o 

(where o = vertex, x = unit edge perpendicular to the representation plane, f = pair of vertices at $f$-scaled distance), while the great icosahedron has lace city
 o   o 
   x   
v     v
   x   
 o   o 

(where o and x is same as above, while v = pair of vertices at $v$-scaled distance).
Note that in the above picture the triangular faces are represented by the left-most x (as its base) and either the upper-neighbouring or lower-neighbouring o (as its tip). Accordingly the dihedral angle there is $\arccos(-\sqrt 5 /3) = 138.189685°$. In the lower picture the triangular faces are represented e.g. by the upper x (as its base) and either the bottom-left or bottom-right o (as its tip): Accordingly the dihedral angle here is $\arccos(\sqrt 5 /3) = 41.810315°$.
Therefrom, I think you might be able to deduce further angles.
E.g. when it comes to your mentioned angle $\alpha$, then you are right indeed. The face of the encasing small stellated dodecahedron is a pentagram. (In fact the edge skeletton of the great icosahedron and that of the small stellated dodecahedron are the same.) The intersection of the 5 triangles of the vertex above that plane describe the smaller pentagram within. Then take a look onto the blue inscribed pentagons: your angle $\alpha$ is just one of their corner angles, which indeed is $108°$.

--- rk
Edit: (further formulae)
You probably know that the circumradius of the regular convex (unit-edged) icosahedron is
$$R_c(ike)=\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}{8}} = 0.951057$$
Therefrom one derives by means of the above mentioned scaling of the vertex set the circumradius of the (unit-edged) great icosahedron to be
$$R_c(gike)=\frac1{\varphi}R_c(ike)=\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt5}{8}} = 0.587785$$
By means of Pythagoras and the (2D) circumradius of the (unit-edged) regular triangle one derives the (3D) inradius of the (unit-edged) great icosahedron to be
$$R_i(gike)=\sqrt{R^2_c(gike)-r^2_c(trig)}=\sqrt{\frac{7-3\sqrt5}{24}} = 0.110264$$
When it comes to the surface area as well to the volume of non-convex polyhedra, you surely have to distinguish between those values of those $true$ polyhedra themselves and the corresponding values of their periforms. Periforms would neglect any internal bit of their facets, just keeping the outer chunks. Thereby they additional introduce further edges at the face-intersections as well as additional vertices at the edge-intersections (old and new!). Thus the periform of the great icosahedron clearly would have $9\times 20=180$ facet chunks, $180\times 3/2=270$ edge snippets, and $12+20+5\times 12=92$ vertices within 3 different orbits of symmetry.
Thence, when considering the $true$ great icosahedron, it still is bounded by $20$ regular (unit-edged) triangles, thence its surface is exactly the same as that of the regular (unit-edged) convex icosahedron, i.e.
$$A(gike)=A(ike)=20\times A(trig)=20\times\frac{\sqrt3}4=5\sqrt3=8.660254$$
With respect to the volume of the $true$ great icosahedron it becomes likewise easy. It simply is obtained by the volumes of $20$ pyramids with bases being the faces (the regular triangles) and the tip being the body-center. Thence their heights are just the afore given inradius. - Sure, these pyramids will be mutually intersecting, but this just accounts for according multiple density regions in the right way! These regions then would have multiple en-wrapping facets above. - Thus
$$V(gike)=\frac13 A(gike) R_i(gike)=\frac5{12}(3-\sqrt5)=0.318305$$
For further details cf. to

Great icosahedron (polytope-wiki)
Great icosahedron (wikipedia)


Thanks!  I prefer using the simplest approaches possible - is there a way to use the Law of Cosines or another trig formula to find $\theta$ and the height of the purple triangle from there?  (Or even find $\alpha$ in the first place.)

From the pic of the mutually enclosed pentagrams you get that the outer arms of the pentagram are $1/\varphi^2$ of the edge size. And the medial edge remainder, outlining the smaller pentagon, then is $1/\varphi^3$. The dissection line, outlining the inscribed pentagram, thus is $\varphi/\varphi^3=1/\varphi^2$, and thence the outer arm length of that dissection line pentagram is $1/\varphi^4$ (the red one in your pic).
Thus you have 2 sides as well as the contained corner angle (60°), thence you would be able to evaluate the missing yellow side of that triangle as well as your angle $\Theta$.
